# use query srting in url for making a request to api and use that output back in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, url

everyone.

- I have a script in my website that adds prefix to  all external links
  like `mywebsite.com/redirect_to/?url=externallink.com`
- So, assume that you are browsing a page
  `mywebsite.com/redirect_to/?url=gooogle.com`

i created `.htaccess` rules to handle that request with    `redirect_to.php` that contains

`<a href="<?php $url = $_GET["url"]; echo htmlspecialchars($url); ?>">External Link</a>`

1. This whole process is fine.

Now, i want to convert that original external link we see in redirect_to.php to short URL

That short URL api works like this:

when we browse `someurlshortener.com/api.php?url=http://google.com` we get `http://someurlshortener.com/6421`

similarly i made `<a href="<?php $var = file_get_contents('http://someurlshortener.com/api.php?url=https://google.com'); $output = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $var); print $output; ?>">Shortened Link</a>`

that gave an output `http://someurlshortener.com/34566`

2. This API request is also working fine.

Then i tried to combine both of these codes. Like

```
<a href="<?php $var = file_get_contents('http://someurlshortener.com/api.php?url=<?php $url = $_GET["url"]; echo htmlspecialchars($url); ?>'); $output = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $var); print $output; ?>">Is it shortened?</a>
```

this gave an output linked to `http://mywebsite.com/redirect_to/?url=https://google.com` which is page itself.

3. This is not working as i wanted.

So, please help me fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing that much inline in the actual link just makes the code hard to read, reuse and easy to make mistakes in. For example: `file_get_contents('http://someurlshortener.com/api.php?url=<?php $url = ...` <== here you're trying to open a php-block inside a php-block, which doesn't really work.

My suggestion is to create a function that does this, it will make it much easier to read, reuse and maintain. Change it once and it will change everywhere.

Add the following somewhere in your scripts, before you're going to use it:

```
function buildUrl($url)
{
    // Url encode the link so we can use it in the 
    // query string without breaking anything.
    $url = urlencode($url);

    // Get the short url
    $url = file_get_contents('http://someurlshortener.com/api.php?url=' . $url);

    // Parse the result
    $url =  preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $url);

    // Return the result
    return $url;
}
```

Then, in your HTML, you only need to call the function, like this:

```
<a href="<?= buildUrl($_GET['url']) ?>">Some link</a>
```

Comment: Works, like charm,
By the way, don't mind. i am new to php.

Comment: @SatishNetha No worries. Everyone has been new to it at one point or another. Just keep at it and don't hesitate to ask if you get stuck. That's why this site exists. :-)